# How to find a four square-equations matrix with only one known equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Sorry if the title isn't very descriptive. However, I've seen the following problem while I'm solving linear problems

> Write down $E=||Ax-b||^2$ as a sum of four squares - the last one is $(C+4D-20)^2$. Find the derivative equations $\partial E/\partial C=0$ and $\partial E/\partial D=0$. Divide by $2$ to obtain the normal equations $A^TA\hat{x}=A^Tb$.

with the given solution

> Observe $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1 &0\\1 &1\\1 &3\\1 &4\\\end{pmatrix}\text{, }b=\begin{pmatrix}0\\8\\8\\20\end{pmatrix}\text{ , and define }x=\begin{pmatrix}C\\D\end{pmatrix}$$
>
> > $$Ax-b=\begin{pmatrix}C\\C+D-8\\C + 3D − 8\\C + 4D − 20\\\end{pmatrix}\text{, }$$
> >
> > > $||Ax − b||^2 = C^2 + (C + D − 8)^2 + (C + 3D − 8)^2 + (C + 4D − 20)^2$
> > >       .

Where do the values of the matrix A come from? I don't find any relative thing in the question. Thanks.

Comment: What have you worked out so far ?

Comment: i believe in your notations $A$ is the feature-matrix and $b$ is your observations. They are given in order to obtain an estimate for your vector $x$, i.e. to compute $\hat{x}$.

Comment: @pointguard0 Yea, but how did we get both **_A_** and **_b_** values, they were given in the solution.

Comment: you cannot minimze $\| Ax - b\|_2^2$ without having observed values of $A$ and $b$, please edit your question adding the complete formulation of your task.

Comment: I guess there's a mistake in the problem itself formulation from the original source